# how to get device 's temperature in android

Tags: android, sensors, temperature

I want to get temperature from device. but I don t know how I can do. please help me writing simple.
thanks.

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985396/is-there-any-android-api-to-find-sense-room-temperature-programmatically-in-andr

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE) for battery or CPU temperature. [TYPE_TEMPERATURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_TEMPERATURE) is the depcrecated constant.

The modified version of code available at [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) should be like  this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

public class TempSensorActivity extends Activity, implements SensorEventListener {
 private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
 private final Sensor mTempSensor;

 public TempSensorActivity() {
     mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
     mTempSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
 }

 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mTempSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
 }

 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
 }

 public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
 }

 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
 }
}
```

Look at [sensor documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) for more.

Comment: This is very helpful but there's a more complete answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29285300/1617737

Comment: Why do system return null for  mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE)   on every device that I test? Other apps display the temperature on the same device. How it is possible? For example, I use Samsung S9 and system returns null too.

Comment: Same null problem as @PonomarenkoOleh ... any one solved this issue?