# Broadcast receiver to detect when the device is reaching its maximum temperature

Tags: android

I am working on android application which needs the function to alert the user, when the device is reaching its maximum **CPU temperature**.

Is there any existing `broadcast receiver` to detect the **CPU** Temperature ?? or Whats the best way to achieve this ??

Note: Know that the CPU temperature can be pulled from `sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`, but looking for a solution to receive through the broadcast.

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11931903/4168607) will help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get CPU temperature in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797869/how-to-get-cpu-temperature-in-android)

Comment: @NileshDeokar : The solution you referred, need to pull data every time. But my case is the application needs to be alerted even when it runs backgrond.

Comment: @ADM : TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE will provide us room temperature, but not the CPU temperature

Comment: You might have to create a `Service` and add `SensorEventListener` to it. and from there if it reaches the threshold level you can use `LocalBroadcastManager` to update app state

Comment: @NileshDeokar : If I am not wrong, the Temperature Sensor in Android will provide us room temperature, but not the CPU temperature right ??

Comment: Have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11931903/3746306

Comment: Thanks @ADM and NileshDeokar : Just noticed that the sensor TYPE_TEMPERATURE which used to detect Device temperature is depricated , and suggested to use TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE.