# Sampling Android Sensors

Tags: android, android-sensors, timertask

Is there a way to get the values from an Android sensor say every 5 minutes?

For example, is there a way I can poll the AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE sensor every 5 minutes regardless of there being a change in temperature or not?

Right now, I can only access the values from `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0)` when it gets called so if the temperature didn't change from start up, I never can access the temperature value?

Thanks! =]

Comment: have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985396/is-there-any-android-api-to-find-sense-room-temperature-programmatically-in-andr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I recall the senors return a value every `onSensorChanged`-event. You can set up a thread, that reads in the values every 5 minutes.

**Edit**:

```
public class OrientationHandler implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager sensorManager = null;
    private static float[] values = new float[3];

    public OrientationHandler(Context context) {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager
                                       .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
                                       SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
            synchronized (this) {
                OrientationHandler.values = event.values;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OrientationHandler.values can be accessed from outside the class (if you write yourself a public Getter-method).

Comment: yeah, but what it it never changed so it doesn't get called ever? My problem is getting the first value. I wrote up a test app to try it out and I can't get the "ambient temperature" value because `onSensorChanged` never got called?

Comment: save the values in the onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) to a class variable that can be accessed from outside.

Comment: so onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) will only update that class variable.

Comment: oh *now* I've got your problem. Damn. Its late over here.

Comment: but I never even get to `onSensorChanged` so there's no way to initialize that class variable with anything useful. I just read the link you posted and yeah.. the battery temperature would be pretty useless for me. Thanks for the help though! =]

Comment: have you tried something like Log.i(TAG, "onSensorChanged was called") inside onSensorChanged() to check if it is called initially? If it will not be called I would file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an alarm service an setting it repeating every five minutes.

I never worked with sensors though, anyway I think there is some way to get the sensor value once.

I suggest you to read [this first](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html) and then [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/schedule-repeating-alarm.html) to learn how to set a repeating alarm which on it's broadcast receiver could update your sensor info.

Hope this helps =)